# Validation exception even with ValidateRequest="false"

Tags: asp.net, security, asp.net-3.5, webforms, validate-request

I have a textbox in a web form where an admin user can add HTML to be submitted for entry into the database.

In the past, I've always added `ValidateRequest="false"` to the `Page` when submitting HTML data to avoid validation error. However, with this website, even with `ValidateRequest` set to `false`, I'm getting the following error:

> A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the
>   client

I've heard this is to do with .NET 4 security, but this is an ASP.NET 3.5 application.

Why am I still getting this error?

Comment: what are you actually posting?

Comment: why dont you encode it ?

Comment: This is webforms right, and not MVC?

Comment: @JamesJohnson Indeed. Retagged.

Comment: @RoyiNamir - Do you mean `Server.HtmlEncode`? This doesn't work, your encoding server side so its still passing HTML with the form which is against security.

Comment: can you upload the aspx code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RequestValidation has significant changes in .Net 4.0.

Take a lot at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.requestvalidationmode(VS.100).aspx

To solve your problem you have to set requestValidationMode to a value less than 4.0 in httpRuntime in weh.config like this:

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are nervous about setting the request validation back to .net 2 - just add a location flag to web config (along with setting ValidateRequestMode="Disabled" on the text box you want to allow special chars in). The location setting in web.config is like this:

```
  <location path="login.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

See excellent article, and comments, regarding this here: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2010/Aug/19/RequestValidation-Changes-in-ASPNET-40